# MSBuild : Global Asax not Included

Tags: msbuild, teamcity, global-asax

We have an MSBuild task that runs on our server after pulling down code as an automated build server.

Our problem is that when we deploy the site from the output of MSBuild, there are a few files included that shouldn't be and one (maybe more) that aren't included.

These are the files that are included that shouldn't

```
mscorlib.dll
normidna.nlp
normnfc.nlp
normnfd.nlp
normnfk.nlp
normnfkd.nlp
```

And this is the one file that I'm aware of that's missing

```
App_global.asax.compiled
```

The server it's building on is Windows Server 2008 64-bit
I'm using TeamCity to run the builds if this makes a difference

Any other details that are needed, please feel free to comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With regard to the files that are included that should not be, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604221/why-does-the-deployment-package-from-my-buildserver-have-additional-assemblies) question seems to have the answer which is that the build server does not have the .NET framework SDK installed.

As for the missing App_global.asax.compiled the final answer posted in [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1841165.aspx/1) thread suggests that if you have a web application project rather than a web site project then you won't get one of these files.

Comment: I found the answer about 4 hours after posting but didn't update this question to reflect, but this was what the problem was. Thanks :)