# additional files after publishing in .net project

Tags: c#, .net, publish

I am building C# application seperately for 32bit and 64bit machine. After publishing the folder generated for 64bit machine contains some extra files (.nlp files) . what is the reason for it and how to remove these extra files ?

I referred [Why does the deployment package from my buildserver have additional assemblies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604221/why-does-the-deployment-package-from-my-buildserver-have-additional-assemblies) ,but it didnot resolve my problem .

Is there any other way to solve it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does the deployment package from my buildserver have additional assemblies?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604221/why-does-the-deployment-package-from-my-buildserver-have-additional-assemblies)

Comment: i tried all the methods told in <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604221/why-does-the-deployment-package-from-my-buildserver-have-additional-assemblies> but it didnot help me