# Azure Build Pipeline: VSBuild fails on The CodeDom provider

Tags: azure, azure-devops, msbuild, azure-pipelines, codedom

My build pipeline (Microsoft-hosted agent) has been running every morning for a couple of months but this morning it suddenly failed on the VSBuild task. The error is described as:

"##[error]ASPNETCOMPILER(0,0): Error ASPCONFIG: The CodeDom provider type "Microsoft.VisualC.CppCodeProvider, CppCodeProvider, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" could not be located."

[See image of failed build here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01SGZ.png)

How do i fix this?

Comment: My devops build ran fine 11/15/2021. Tried to run the same build from the same git commit today (1/6/2022) and it's failing with this error.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I managed to solve this by just skipping build on the assets project that failed. This was done using the Configuration Manager in Visual Studio (found in Build->Configuration Manager). I just removed the check mark. See attached images for clarification.

[Skip project build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pg8BY.png)

[Configuration Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnpLQ.png)

Comment: Excluding projects is not really a solution.  When trying to build a project that needs the CodeDom configs to build (interpolated strings, for example), excluding that project would not be helpful at all.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if you use private agent. As I know this error could result from the fact that `PrecompileBeforePublish` property is set to `true` somewhere in your project.(csproj or publish profile).

As one workaround you can pass `/p:PrecompileBeforePublish=false` as argument to your VSBuild Task. But this may make first response of your application slow.

Or you can register it into GAC using command like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57413826/10910450):

```
gacutil /i "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\xxxx\VSEditon\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\CppCodeProvider.dll"
```

Cause after VS2017, the C++ project support for `xsd.exe` is deprecated, we need to manually add its assembly into GAC as described [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/240322/cppcodeprovider-not-properly-installed-with-vs2017.html).

Comment: Microsoft-hosted agent

Comment: @Halling Hi Halling, the first workaround above should work for both self and hosted agents, have you tried that?

Comment: The GAC portion of this "answer" is not useful given the precondition of Azure Pipeline